# Don't give access to purchased apps to other users of a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts, license

At work, I use a Mac with OSX 10.9.2 and I use my personal App Store account on it.

I have to create an account for my colleagues on this Mac too.

Will they have access too all the apps I have bought with my account ? If yes, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you know the parental controls?

Answer (score 2):

Parental controls are one way to go, as @Alienlebarge suggested. Another option is to move the apps out of the app folder into your own personal folder. After installing, move them away to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @SPRBRN, if you create an Applications folder in your home directory, OSX will treat this as a proper Applications folder, allowing registration of programs that you add there and only you will be able to access them.

Note that when you install a program, either by copying it into the Applications folder, or downloading it from the AppStore, the application is registered with the system.

So I suggest you create an Applications folder in your home directory and move the apps there.